# Ubuntu does not recognize Windows 10 for installation

Tags: boot, windows

I want to dual boot Windows 10 and Ubuntu 14.04.3. I just installed Windows 10 on my 1TB hard drive. No other drives in the machine.

Made an ~400gb unallocated partition of space on the drive. Started Ubuntu installation from a flash drive.

It says that it appears there are no other operating systems on the computer and provides me only with options to completely wipe the drive and install Ubuntu, or do something else (bringing me to a panel from which I can make new partitions and whatnot).

Ubuntu only recognizes my hard drive as 1TB of entirely unallocated space, though it clearly has Windows 10 successfully booting and functioning on half of it.

Suggestions? Help?

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! Please open a terminal in the live system and execute `sudo parted -l`, then add the result as an [edit] to your question.

Comment: Did you find the solution?

Answer (score 0):

Choose "Something else"

Select the free space and divide it into two partitions. One around 4-5GB and the other for Ubuntu.

Format the smaller partition as Swap.

Format the partition designated for Ubuntu preferably as ext4.

Select that partition and Install Ubuntu.

Choose / as mount point for bootloader.

Follow On-screen steps for completing the installation.

After the installation, you will be asked to choose from Ubuntu or Windows recovery partition. Windows recovery partition is actually your windows 10 installation.

Make sure you backup important files first in case something goes wrong.